# hibernate groupby

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to know how to make groupby in hibernate. 
my code is below but it is not working please tell me how do this :

```
Session session = getSession();
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(CardLog.class);
c.add(Restrictions.ge(CARD_PUNCHING_TIME, todaysDate));
c.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty(USER_ID));
c.addOrder(Order.desc(USER_ID));
cardLogList = c.list();                
System.out.println("----------------" + cardLogList);
```

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Are there any errors? What's the output when you enable [sql output](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html) using `hibernate.show_sql=true`  and enable `org.hibernate.SQL`Logging

Comment: When you use `group by` it's usually goes with an aggregation function (sum, count, max, min). What are you trying to request from the database? n other words, what is your request supposed to return?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use like this

```
Session session = getSession();
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(CardLog.class);
c.add(Restrictions.ge("bean property todaydate", todaysDate));
c.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("bean property userId"));
c.addOrder(Order.desc("bean property userId"));
cardLogList = c.list();                
System.out.println("----------------" + cardLogList);
```

Comment: my list(cardLogList) is databean list so it not allowed me to add projectionlist..